# Splunk to avoid duplication of data pulled by REST API

Tags: rest, api, splunk

I have splunk instance where i configure Data Inputs as "REST API input for polling data from RESTful endpoints".
I have almost around 20+ endpoints and where i am pulling data in json format and loading in single index.

However each time any reports or search query runs it will double same data again like very first fetch brings 5 values and subsequent fetch will bring another 5 and so and keep increasing.

Now in my dashboards and reports i kind of landed into problem of duplicate data. How i should avoid it.
So for very unusual work around i increased interval from 1 min to 1 months which helps me to avoid data duplication.
However i cannot have stale data for month...i can still survive with 1 day interval but not with 1 month.

**Is there any way in splunk where i can keep my REST API Call tidy(avoid duplicates) ... to make my dashboards and  reports on the fly.**

Here is snippet of my inputs.conf file for REST API.

```
[rest://rst_sl_get_version]
auth_password = ccccc
auth_type = basic
auth_user = vvvvvvv
endpoint = https://api.xx.com/rest/v3/xx_version
host = slrestdata
http_method = GET
index = sldata
index_error_response_codes = 0
response_type = json
sequential_mode = 0
sourcetype = _json
streaming_request = 0
polling_interval = 2592000
```

Comment: Are the two sets exactly the same, or is it sending the old (original) set of data plus a new (updated or different) set?

Comment: it will be more like i would like do computation only on latest data comes through API. and i am not much bother about the old data...

Comment: Are you asking how to delete old data and replace it with new data?

Comment: Yes ... we can say that ... as well ... since when ever i make REST API calls its brings new data and i am not bother about old which was there in last call.

Answer (score 0):

To remove data that you no longer need or want, you can use the `clean` command:

```
splunk clean eventdata -index <index_name>
```

From the [Splunk documentation](http://docs.splunk.com/Documentation/Splunk/5.0/Indexer/RemovedatafromSplunk#Remove_data_from_one_or_all_indexes):

> To delete indexed data permanently from your disk, use the CLI clean command. This command completely deletes the data in one or all indexes, depending on whether you provide an  argument. Typically, you run clean before re-indexing all your data.

The caveat with this method is that you have to stop Splunk before executing `clean`. If you wanted to automate the process, you could write a script to stop Splunk, run `clean` with your parameters, then restart Splunk.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that every time you make REST API call you have new information you could code a new responsehandler atached in splunkweb/etc/app/rest_ta/bin/responsehandlers.py to include a new field to your json data, (an Id of report reportTime=ff/hh/yyyy h:m:s) so when coding your dashboard you would have a new field with which you could dynamically get last ID to report and at the same time save an historic of your data reports to get more business information.

```
class RestGetCustomField:

     def __init__(self,**args):
         pass

     def __call__(self, response_object,raw_response_output,response_type,req_args,endpoint):
         if response_type == "json":        
             output = json.loads(raw_response_output)
             for flight in output["Data"]:
             flight2.update({"My New Field":datetoday()})
                     print_xml_stream(json.dumps(flight2))
         else:
             print_xml_stream(raw_response_output)
def datetoday():
    today = datetime.date.today()
    return today.strftime('%Y/%m/%d')
```

And then you could configure:

```
response_handler = RestGetCustomField
```

And that's it, now the indexed data have a new field that you can use to identify and or filter reports